# Trying to understand the error on my JS clock

Tags: javascript

I tried to complete one of the OpenClassRoom exercises for JavaScript, in this exercise you have to write some code that will "tell you" which time will it be in one second, so there is my code, but when I run it, I have an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: heures is not defined at `<anonymous>:6:18`

```js
    let heures = 14;
    let minutes = 17;
    let secondes = 59;

    if ((minutes === 59) && (secondes === 59))
      {
        let heures = Number(heures)+1
        let minutes = 00
        let secondes = 00
        console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) 
      }

    else if ((secondes === 59) && (minutes !== 59))
      {
        let heures = heures
        let minutes = minutes+1
        let secondes = 00
        console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) 
      }

    else if ((heures === 23) && (minutes === 59) && (secondes === 59))
      {
        let heures = 00
        let minutes = 00
        let secondes = 00
        console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) 
      }
  
    else if ((heures !== 23) && (minutes !== 59) && (secondes !== 59))
      {
        let heures = heures
        let minutes = minutes
        let secondes = secondes + 1
        console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) 
      }
```

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-declaring your variables with [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) which is what is causing the error. `let` is used to create "block scoped variables" and since you were using it within different blocks of your `if` statement, you were actually creating different variables with the same name, but with different scopes.

You only need to declare the variable one time and then you can re-assign a value to it as needed.

```js
let heures = 14;
let minutes = 17;
let secondes = 59;

if ((minutes === 59) && (secondes === 59)) {
   heures = Number(heures) + 1;
   minutes = 00;
   secondes = 00;
   //console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":" + secondes) ;
} else if ((secondes === 59) && (minutes !== 59)) {
   //heures = heures; <-- Setting a variable to itself makes no change to the program
   minutes = minutes + 1;
   secondes = 00;
   //console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) ;
} else if ((heures === 23) && (minutes === 59) && (secondes === 59)) {
   heures = 00;
   minutes = 00;
   secondes = 00;
   //console.log(heures+":"+minutes+":"+secondes) ;
} else if ((heures !== 23) && (minutes !== 59) && (secondes !== 59)) {
   //heures = heures;    <-- Setting a variable to itself makes no change to the program
   //minutes = minutes;  <-- Setting a variable to itself makes no change to the program
   secondes = secondes + 1;
   //console.log(heures+":" + minutes + ":" + secondes);
}
// No need to have this in each branch of the if statement
// when you want to do it in all cases.
console.log(heures+":" + minutes + ":" + secondes);
```

Comment: @LaFeeDeration Check out my comments that I've just added and don't forget to up vote and mark this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.